# Visual Studio for Linux Manjaro

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I am still learning code and one of the things that is constantly asking me for tutorials and assignments is that I use visual studio. However, recently I installed Linux Manjaro OS and things are definitely different than windows OS in which I am used to. It is taking some time to learn everything about this. I have over 10+ years with Windows OS and only Windows OS LOL. Anyways, I saw a post that while VS is not a Linux friendly program, Visual Studio Code the lighter version is. The problem I have is, which install is best for my Manjaro version? [image]

Comment: Have you considered installing through `snap`? https://snapcraft.io/install/code/manjaro  Google "Install vscode manjaro", and plenty shows up.

Comment: Manjaro uses neither .dep nor .rpm. But .tar.gz or a snap version might work. VSC is just a glorified notepad (unlike VS), so you'll also need a compiler.

Comment: Another approach might be to read the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), of [git](https://git-scm.com/), of [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), of [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/). Together, they are a good replacement of Visual Studio Code (and available on most Linux distribution). **Be aware of the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)**.

Comment: I only tried looking it up through pamac and CodeSS only came up. I tried CodeSS but it is difficult to work with. I will try .tar and look for a compiler. Since I'm new to linux it will take me a minute. I will let you know how it goes. ty~.

Comment: Learning Linux could be fun, but takes months of efforts. Linux is not Windows.

Comment: I have only had LInux for a month give or take a week or two. My course after next in UPOX is set on C# with a focus on ASP.Net so I wanted to get started on practicing but again, Linux Manjaro and VS what the hangup was. By the way it is not Code SS I left off an O it is Code OSS that pamac has. Not sure why people say pacman? Anwyays, I installed the GCC compiler and snap is included in Manjaro, but the only thing I can use is the Code OSS as a sub so I will have to learn to work around certain things. Thanks everyone!

Comment: By the way, for those interested in why I do not like Code OSS, it is because when I need to add another file to the one I am working on, it does not like to let me. Such as if I need another file/folder to hold certain code that will affect my main and need it to be able to go back and forth between them is my biggest problem. Like notes, I have open a completely separate IDE of Code OSS than my main just to do this action unless someone else has more experience in this department and has figured out what I could not.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the vscode package with `sudo pacman -Syu code` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would warn against downloading files without using the manjaro package manager `pacman` or `pamac`.
One of the premises of Linux, and especially distros based upon arch such as Manjaro is the utility and ubiquity of the Terminal.  I started using Manjaro this year, and definitely one of the most difficult things to get used to is the reliance upon the terminal.
Linux-schpeel aside, the easiest way to install programs or packages on Manjaro is to type `pamac install` for standard packages or `pamac build` forr packages from the AUR.
In your case, I would recommend installing `visual-studio-code-bin` as it allows you to run a wider variety of extensions such as the Windows `C/C++` extension.

So in a line: `pamac build visual-studio-code-bin` for pamac

Good luck out there and welcome to the linux community! :D